# insert json data into postgres database using java program

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql, insert

I'm looking for help to insert json data into postgres table using java program. I have tried with following code but cannot find any data is inserted in to the table. I have very little experience in programming. Can some one help me to modify my program to make it work?

here is my code.

```
enter code here  stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE jason " +
                "(ID INT      NOT NULL," +
                " NAME           json    NOT NULL)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); //updates the table
       //json data----------------
        String[] MESSAGE = {"{\"customer_name\": \"John\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"milk\", \"quantity\": 4 } }"};

        sql = "INSERT INTO jason (ID,NAME) "
                + "VALUES (1,::MESSAGE );";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use parameters in a statement, you need to use a prepared statement:

```java
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO jason (ID,NAME) VALUES (1,?)" );
stmt.setString(1, "{\"customer_name\": \"John\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"milk\", \"quantity\": 4 } }");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks all. prepared statement thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with syntax here, please read this instruction: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

It's should be:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO jason (ID,NAME) VALUES (1, ?1);");
pstmt.setString(1, yourJsonString)
```

Comment: Plain JDBC uses `?` as the placeholder, **not** `?1` (which is clearly stated in the link you posted)